# An Error in Converting android JSON to UTF-8

Tags: android, android-json

i am using volley and JSON in my app to recive data from mysql and show in my application.

my database has 3 fields : image-name-publisher
my publisher field is persian language and it should be UTF-8

**This is my code:**

```
    //This method will parse json data
private void parseData(JSONArray array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        //Creating the superhero object
        SuperHero superHero = new SuperHero();
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            //Getting json
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            //Adding data to the superhero object
            superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString("image"));
            superHero.setName(json.getString("name"));

            superHero.setPublisher(json.getString("publisher").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Adding the superhero object to the list
        listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
    }

    //Notifying the adapter that data has been added or changed
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

as you can see , im using getByte to convert it to utf-8 but this line has error like this :

**Unhandled Exception:java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException**

i have really problem with that

what should i do??

Thank you very much

Comment: When you server is repsonding in utf-8 and your client communicates over http using utf-8, then the string comming from the json object is already decoded.

Comment: The error refers to the `ISO-8859-1` in your `getBytes()` call

Comment: ok what should i do now? can you help me more? thank you

Comment: what are you expecting this to do? (what it actually does is: take the string, encode it in iso, then try to decode the bytes as if they were utf. which they aren't, so it fails)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use String constructor to convert UTF-8 characters :

```
String publisher = new String(json.getString("publisher").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Also maybe the problem is from the given encoding "ISO-8859-1"
[docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29) / [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)